# how to decide sigma for FFT based Gaussian filter

Tags: filter, fft, gaussianblur

I am using a FFT-based guassian low pass filter and was wondering how to decide D0 in equation:

```
exp(-(D(u,v)^2/2D0^2))
```

Since I am filtering a 2D image, so how can I relate D0 to pixel size? For gaussian filter in the spatial domain, I typically use the standard deviation of the whole image as sigma (or multiple times of the standard deviation). So, is there a formula that can relate the standard deviation in the spatial domain to D0?

Thanks.

Comment: The relationship between the sigma in the spatial domain and the frequency domain is well established. See for example here: https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf — how to chose a sigma, however, depends on the application and the data, we can’t help you there.

Comment: Thanks Cris. If I have the variance of a signal, can I use it as D0 to construct a low pass Gaussian filter kernel? Using the variance means the majority of the low frequency signals are kept.

Comment: Filter parameters are dependent on more than noise strength. How much noise can you allow in the output? How much smoothing can you allow in the output? Or maybe you need to use a non-linear denoising filter?

Comment: I just want to give a default value to the user which is not optimal, of cause, but not too bad at least.